# Three.js / WebGL - transparent planes hiding other planes behind them

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, depth, zbuffer

When you have two planes in Three.js / WebGL and one or both of them are transparent, sometimes the plane behind will be hidden by the transparent plane above. Why is this?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127242/opengl-rendering-two-transparent-planes-intersecting-each-other-impossible-or)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's just how OpenGL (and, hence, WebGL) works. Transparent surfaces don't play well with the z-buffer, and as such must be manually sorted and rendered back-to-front. Three JS is attempting to do this for you (which is why the problem goes away when you set the X value > 0) but cannot robustly handle the case of intersecting geometry like you're showing.

I've explained the issue more in-depth in a [different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763603/transparent-textures-behaviour-in-webgl), so you may want to reference that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but so you are telling me it's better just to redesign my game or is a solution pursuitable hacking Three.JS?

Comment: @Toji the question you refer to is not dealing with exactly the same issue. In the other question it is only part of the object/texture that is transparent where in this question the whole plane is transparent and this is easily solvable by simply deactivating the `depthWrite` totally for the transparent plane.

Answer (score 26):

Setting the `depthWrite` property to `false` solved my issue.

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    opacity: 0.25, 
    transparent: true, 
    side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
    depthWrite: false
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU. No more "transparent black box problem"!

Comment: 6 years later, thank you Wilt.

Answer (score 25):

Let's say that you are using some transparent *.png image. Then this would help:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    depthWrite: false,
    depthTest: false,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    map: texture
});
```

Comment: For some reason the `side: THREE.BackSide` part stopped my images from rendering all-together. But aside from that, the rest worked great!

Comment: You probably want to use THREE.DoubleSide so it's visible from both sides.

Comment: It works in my case, but what are the implications? What cases will now start not working?

Answer (score 21):

Try adding `alphaTest: 0.5` to the material.

Comment: Have tried that, didn't work :/ I guess it is an webgl problem so I have to redesign how my game is displaying planes. It'll look a bit hacked though.

Comment: I have a plane with a canvas-based texture mapped to it displaying text. At certain angles/positions I was having issues with the transparency of the texture material and this fixed it, so thanks!

Comment: Note: `alphaTest` is a treshold that will make semi-transparent areas in textures either fully opaque (when pixel opacity > treshold) or fully transparent (when pixel opacity < treshold). This may result in ugly edges.

Answer (score 6):

fwiw, if you have lots of parallel planes (can't see your sample, google can't resolve your domain), it's easy to keep them sorted along the perpendicular axis. For a list of planes [A B C D] the order-to-draw will be either [A B C D] or [D C B A] and nothing else! So there need not be a performance hit from sorting. Just keep them in order as you go.

Comment: the problem is that I have some planes that should be rendered crossing the others. Like if they were 3d flat swords. Might I ask, how did you find that question so long after it was asked and how did 4 upvoters come here?

Comment: Your questions abut people's behavior I cannot answer :) However, if you have polygons that cross one another, there is no easy correct solution other than per-fragment ones like K-Buffers or the original A-Buffer algorithm, unless you specifically police the triangle intersections and tesselate them on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Setting Mesh `renderOrder` to solve my problem, below is my code, you can **modify** `node.renderOrder` value:

```
loader.load(model_url, (gltf)=>{
            let scene = gltf.scene

            scene.traverse((node)=>{

                if(node.isMesh){
                    node.material.transparent = true

                    if(node.name === 'car_windows'){
                        node.material.opacity = 0.4
                        node.material.side = 0
                        node.renderOrder = 110
                    }

                    if(node.name === 'car_body'){
                        node.material.opacity = 0.4
                        node.renderOrder = 100
                    }

                    if(node.name === 'car_seats'){
                        node.material.opacity = .5
                        node.renderOrder = 90
                    }

                    mesh_arr.push(node)
                    mesh_objs[node.name] = node
                }
            })
})
```

Comment: Although, the answer doesn't include any examples and not really descriptive, this is the only option worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @Footniko Sorry for no example code, I've added it, hope it help. :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, don't use the literal boolean value true try using 1 instead.

```
object3d.material.transparent = 1;
```