# 2 of the same planes in a group, both aren't transparent

Tags: three.js

I have a plane mesh and I duplicated them and put them in a Object3d group, and they are both suppose to be transparent, but only one of them is, please help.

```
face = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('face.png')
});
face.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
face.map.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;

facePlane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100), face);

faceGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
faceGroup.add(facePlane.clone());
faceGroup.add(facePlane.clone());
faceGroup.children[0].rotation.y = 90*(Math.PI/180);

scene.add(faceGroup);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution on [Three.js / WebGL - transparent planes hiding other planes behind them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165345/three-js-webgl-transparent-planes-hiding-other-planes-behind-them)

adding `alphaTest: 0.5` to the material.