# Three.js - transparent objects when rotated with TrackballControls don't behave like transparent

Tags: three.js, transparency, opacity, zbuffer

When I add to the scene two objects and set their transparency as true with some opacity and using TrackballControls I rotate the scene by mouse, the object which was initially further from camera loses its transparency.

I read that this is Z-buffer problem and further objects from camera will be displayed first. But when I rotate the scene using TrackballControls, camera changes its position, so transparent objects should be displayed correctly. But it is not like that.

Here in this picture - on the right is frontview, on the left is backview which is not displayed correctly:

http://www.foto-ondruskova.cz/Experiment/lenses.jpg

Please, any solutions?

Comment: I see a few possibilities, but without code or a demo, all we can do is do a bunch of guesswork.

Comment: I found that somehow in my code there was renderer.sortObjects = false that was causing the problem. Thanks JayC, now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem and setting `alphaTest: 0.5` to the material as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165345/three-js-webgl-transparent-planes-hiding-other-planes-behind-them#answer-11169862) solved my problem. But it is hit and miss. Give it a try. Hopefully it works!