# Why is the opacity different depending on the camera angle?

Tags: aframe, webvr

Upon first loading the scene, when panning left and right, the left bars are semi-transparent, but the right ones are opaque. If you strafe right (key d) of the rightmost bar, all of the bars become transparent.  Is this an issue with lighting or the way I have my light sources set up?

```js
// default alpha for bars
var alpha = 0.6

// fake data
var data = [19, 80, 30, 15, 55, 35, 40,
  45, 50, 70, 109, 35, 78,
  87, 76, 22, 2, 33, 44, 59, 200
]

var animals = ['Bobcat', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Boar', 'Cheetah', 'Chimp', 'Dragon',
  'Elephant', 'Human', 'Elf', 'Giant', 'Batman', 'Donkey',
  'Henry', 'Face', 'Funny', 'Kitty', 'Doggy', 'Joker', 'Alf', 'Earth'
]

// we scale the height of our bars using d3's linear scale
var hscale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
  .range([0, 3])

// we select the scene object just like an svg
var scene = d3.select("a-scene")

// we use d3's enter/update/exit pattern to draw and bind our dom elements
var bars = scene.selectAll("a-box.bar").data(data)
bars.enter().append("a-box").classed("bar", true)

$(".bar").append("<a-text> </a-text>");
// we set attributes on our cubes to determine how they are rendered
bars.attr({
    position: function(d, i) {
      var x = i * .75
      var y = hscale(d) / 2;
      var z = 1
      return x + " " + y + " " + z
    },
    width: function(d) {
      return 0.5
    },
    depth: function(d) {
      return 0.9
    },
    height: function(d) {
      return hscale(d)
    },
    opacity: alpha,
    color: 'blue'
  })
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    console.log("click", i, d)
  })
  .on("mouseenter", function(d, i) {
    // this event gets fired continuously as long as the cursor
    // is over the element. we only want trigger our animation the first time
    if (this.hovering) return;
    console.log("hover", i, d)
    this.hovering = true;
    d3.select(this).transition().duration(10)
      .attr({
        metalness: 0.8,
        opacity: .9
      })
    d3.select(this).select("a-text")
      .attr({
        'color': 'hsla(240, 100%, 25%, 0.6)',
        'align': 'center',
        'position': '0 ' + (hscale(d) / 2 + .5) + ' 0',
        'scale': '1 1 1',
        'value': animals[i] + ', ' + d
      })
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function(d, i) {
    console.log("leave", i, d)
    this.hovering = false;
    d3.select(this).transition().duration(500)
      .attr({
        metalness: 0,
        opacity: alpha
      })
    d3.select(this).select("a-text")
      .attr({
        'color': 'blue',
        'align': 'center',
        'position': '0 ' + (hscale(d) / 2 + .5) + ' 0',
        'scale': '.01 .01 .01',
        'value': d
      })
  })
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <a-scene>
    <a-entity position="8 2 8" rotation="0 0 0">
      <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls>
        <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500" position="0 0 -2" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.027" material="color: black; shader: flat" </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity light="type: point; color: 'white'; intensity: 0.5" position="20 40 20"></a-entity>
      <a-entity light="type: point; color: 'white'; intensity: 0.5" position="-20 40 20"></a-entity>
      <a-sky color="#c8f8e0"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>

  <body>
```

[You can also interact with the HTML Code here.](https://bl.ocks.org/scottlittle/c0c40e2b0aa4a364cc4216cc932e93e7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Three.js / WebGL - transparent planes hiding other planes behind them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165345/three-js-webgl-transparent-planes-hiding-other-planes-behind-them)

> Transparent surfaces don't play well with the z-buffer, and as such must be manually sorted and rendered back-to-front. three.js is attempting to do this for you (which is why the problem goes away depending on the angle of the camera) but cannot robustly handle the case of intersecting geometry like you're showing.

I got it working by changing the material's `alphaTest` value or `depthWrite` values:

```
el.components.material.material.alphaTest = 0.5;
el.components.material.material.depthWrite = false;
el.components.material.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you show me where you added this in the code?

Comment: You can just loop over your elements (`el`) and call it in JavaScript. I'll file an issue to expose those.