# Threejs transparency issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making something that allows users to upload their branding to be printed onto a cup and preview it in 3D using three.js. The issue I'm having is that as you move the camera around the branding can't be seen from behind through the inside of the cup. [See example here.](http://www.stack-cup.com/shop/cup-preview/?file=%2Fshop%2Fimages%2F%3Ffilename%3Dtestlogo.png.DNC23MTSCUqEvu5IH5Cn8sbq64japNe9)

I have made the cup using two cyclinders, one is white at 0.6 transparency to make up the body of the cup and then the other has the branding on it. I've seen [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165345/three-js-webgl-transparent-planes-hiding-other-planes-behind-them) which seems to describe the problem I'm experiencing so is there a different way I can make this to get round this issue? Rather than using two cylinders can I just use 1 that has the white transparent colour and the image applied to it?

Comment: Is the second solution linked in your linked SO question (the one suggesting using `MeshBasicMaterial`) not working ?

Comment: No the type of material doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Even with the same parameters ? Also someone suggested using `THREE.DoubleSide` in the comments.

Comment: Yeah I'm using THREE.DoubleSide at the moment